# Post API : Input methods are empty in restful API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an API post method. When I set `content-type` as form, it sends inputs with value but when I set the `content-type` as JSON it sends all of them null.
I don't know how it is happening?
This is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(model dto)
{
    .......
    return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", mainViewModel);
}
```

Is it possible in somewhere in the code default content-type got changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i set the content-type as json

Try

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]model dto)
    {
        .......
        return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", mainViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: yeah, i know but i think the default content-type is json but here why it doesnt work?

Comment: Have you add the [ApiController] attribute on your controller?

Comment: no i haven't. that is the resaon? @RuikaiFeng

Comment: you could check this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#sources

Comment: without apicontroller attribute the default content would be form? @RuikaiFeng

Comment: That is the reason,if you don't add the Attribute:[ApiController] ,[FromBody],it won't bind data from request body,when you add [ApiController] on your controller,you have to add [FromForm] if you want to bind form values